# What is the property set equality law to solve this proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I have spent too much time on this problem, and I feel as if I am wasting my time by continuing to use the distributive property. Is there an absorption law that I am missing, a value to factor out, or something else? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break it into smaller pieces to see what's going on.

$(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \lnot B) = A \cap (B \cup \lnot B) = A$.

$\lnot A \cap B = B \setminus A$

$A \cup (B \setminus A) = A \cup B$.